# Error while updating my osmdroid package

Tags: android, android-studio, osmdroid

I have been using osmdroid library with android-studio for a while. I recently saw [here](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid) that version 5.4.1 has been released and therefore changed my gradle dependency to

```
compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.4.1:release@aar'
```

But it gives me an error saying

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
Could not find osmdroid-android.aar (org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.4.1).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/osmdroid/osmdroid-android/5.4.1/osmdroid-android-5.4.1.aar
```

Comment: have you tried invalidate cache and restart option ?

Comment: concur, look at the url it's trying to download, it's missing the 'release' bit